# System fan control on ga-ma69g-s3h

Tags: motherboard, fan

I connected videocard fan to SYS FAN on my mobo: ga-ma69g-s3h. Now it rotates all the time with full speed. I want to control it, for example with SpeedFan. Unfortunatelly I can't achieve that. When I change speed of any PWM fields simply nothing happen (only for CPU fan speed changing speed works fine). Do You have any suggestions how can I control speed of that fan?

Answer (score 0):

Many video card fans are controlled with voltage levels, not PWM. If it is the case with your card (which you did not specify) - you won't be able to control it from the motherboard

Comment: Maybe I wrote that not clearly. I connected fan that cools videocard to SYS FAN port on motherboard (videocard port is damaged). So in general that fan can cool something other to. Even if my videocard fan (port to fan) is controlled with voltage levels it doesn't matter because I don;t use that port.